# Programmatically add specific JavaScript to specific questions in Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have 50 pieces of JavaScript code generated in a text file with Python, and currently I have to go click on every of my 50 questions, open up JS editor, then copy and paste the corresponding script from my text file...

I know I can add generic JavaScript code as a header to my survey questions in "look and feel", but that won't work because each piece of my JavaScript code corresponds with a specific question in my survey; also my JS defines a method for the Qualtrics.SurveyEngine object, like `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
///my code
});`
and putting it in header JS doesn't seem to produce any effect.

More background info: I'm implementing an attention check in my survey to make sure the survey takers listen to the audio clip in each question. Every audio element has an ID like "myAudio1", "myAudio2", ... ,"myAudio50", and I generated my attention-check JavaScript code for each question. I imported my 50 questions on Qualtrics, but I don't want to manually "import" those 50 pieces of JS code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript in the Qualtrics header has to be inside a `<script>` tag.

You could add the audio id to a hidden input field in your question text.  Then have the non-question specific JavaScript in the header get that value by id.  This approach would require one question per page so the id is unique.

Example input tag in question text:

```
This is my question text.
<input type="hidden" id="myAudioId" value="myAudio2">
```

In your JavaScript:

```
var myAudioId = $$('myAudioId').value;
```

Comment: But how do you make `Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
});` sort of code work in the header JS? I thought it can only be added via the question's JS editor...

Comment: Sadly nowhere does [this Qualtrics' tutorial](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/developer-tools/custom-programming/survey-javascript-methods/) talk about the header JS approach

Comment: As I said, it has to go inside a `<script>` tag.  JavaScript in the header runs on EVERY page of the survey. You can see an example of JavaScript in a header [here](https://gist.github.com/marketinview/c55e33a2e5ff7e7167e7).

Comment: Sorry it's still not working for me...let's say I just want to hide the choices of my question (1 question per page), so I wrote `<script> Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() { this.hideChoices(); }); </script>` as my header JS--but the choices are still showing... also like you said, with this approach it is, unfortunately, impossible to have two questions per page (which is what I'm using; one real question, the other is the hidden attention-check question with hidden choices "yes" and "no")... Qualtrics people really need to work on these basic JS support issues...

Comment: Your example doesn't work, because 'this' isn't a question. You would have to find the the question first, then hide it (e.g., `$$('QID2').hideChoices();`). The script will work with multiple questions on a page, as long as there is only one id="myAudioId".  So, two audio questions on the same page wouldn't work.

Comment: The approach I gave will work if done properly.  I would have to see all of your JavaScript to help you further.

Comment: I've got it to work with `$$('QID2').hideChoices();`; thanks a lot